# Authenticate to SharePoint Online C#

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, console-application

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint online in a console App and print the title of the site.
Its giving me the error : "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."
I have checked and made sure the username and password are 100% right.
I dont know what else to check
Heres my code:

```
private static void SPCredentialsConnect()
    {
        const string SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite";
        const string pwd = "appPassword";
        const string username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";

        SecureString securestring = new SecureString();
        pwd.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securestring.AppendChar(s));

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securestring);

        try
        {
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine($"web title: {web.Title}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update:
i've tried through AppOnly Authentication and didnt work either:
public static void AppOnlyAuthCall()
        {
            using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, page => page.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.Title);
            };
        }

Comment: when i used this code it tells me "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
and yes  In Azure Active Directory i've granted API permissions (delegated allsites fullcontrol), "allowPublicClient": true, "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": true.

Answer (score 2):

Have your issue fixed? “The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system” Error will occur sometimes and fixed after a while with nothing changed.

AppOnly Authentication for sharepointonline can't be registed in Azure Active Directory.
It should be register in

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

And grant permission in

https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

You can refer to following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Comment: i did register it and granted permission - trust - used the AppConfig and still gives me an error 401 denied with app only auth.
and when connecting throguh SP Credentials its the same error has not fixed (sign-in name or password incorrect)

Comment: Your account may be MFA (Multi-factor authentication) enabled! If yes, either MFA must be turned OFF or you have to follow the methods described in How to Connect to SharePoint Online with MFA-enabled accounts from PowerShell

Comment: MFA is disabled (not set in the first place - and niether by default) this is so weird i tried to make the whole thing all over frmo creating a new account,new tenant , permissions everything all over and still the same of the two errors - using credentials i get"sign-in username or password incorrect" - using authentication manager i get "remote server forbidden 401"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the PnP.Framework ([a NuGet package](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework)), and use the AuthenticationManager object for SPO sites. This method bypasses MFA (which is mandatory in our organization, FWIW). You can find a lot more [information and examples here](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/dev/docs/MigratingFromPnPSitesCore.md), including steps on getting the client id and client secret for a site. Here is what we use to log into SPO sites:

```
using (ClientContext context = 
    new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(SiteUrl, clientID, clientSecret)) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

Also, once you connect, you should adjust the Context.Load to grab the title if you want to use that value right away. Here's what I used in my code:

```
context.Load(web, p => p.Id, p => p.Title);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine($"Logged into source {web.Title} ({web.Id})");
```

Good luck!

Steve in Spain