# How to authenticate to SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

How do you authenticate to SharePoint Online with C#? Error msg: `The identity has not been authenticated.`

```cs
using (ClientContext clientContext = new
  ClientContext("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/")) {
    var passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com",
passWord);

    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    clientContext.Load(web);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);

    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: Is MFA enabled for this user account?

Answer (score 0):

If Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) is enabled for user account, try using App password for login instead of user account password.

**Reference**: [The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275517/the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-microsoft-account-system/275520#275520)

**OR**

Use the `GetWebLoginClientContext` method of SharePoint PnP Core library:

```
AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
using (var context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(URI))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, web => web.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Your site title is: " + context.Web.Title);
}
```

For more information, check:

1. [C# Programmatically Authenticate SharePoint Online account enabled with MFA.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/483620/c-programmatically-authenticate-sharepoint-online.html)
2. [Authentication to Sharepoint Online with CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707476/authentication-to-sharepoint-online-with-csom)
3. [Authenticate to SharePoint Online C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019361/authenticate-to-sharepoint-online-c-sharp)